# Passing user values to variables in AWK. What am I missing?

Tags: linux, r, shell, math, awk

I have a tabular file

```
 V1      V2      V3   V4      V5 V6       V7      V8      V9
chr1 3670715 3671052  338 3670940  8  4.18708 3.36070 2.11284
chr1 3671795 3672053  259 3671953 14  7.60682 4.53642 5.15603
chr1 4491782 4493687 1906 4491915 20 11.42107 5.49862 8.69791
chr1 4491782 4493687 1906 4492254 18  8.58343 4.41588 6.05103
chr1 4491782 4493687 1906 4492555 11  5.49023 3.77545 3.25097
chr1 4491782 4493687 1906 4492907 16  8.45705 4.66761 5.94094
```

I am applying multiple filtering on the file using user inputted values but the result is not correct.

my shell script

```
# Run : sh filter.sh 5 10 20 
fc=$2; pVal=$3; tags=$4
sed 1,29d $1 | awk '$6>int("'$tags'") && $7>int("'$pVal'") && int($8)>int('"$fc"')' | wc -l
```

I am using 3 values and filtering the file (first 29 lines are header) but the output is wrong. I checked in R, it should be `18967` but using above I am getting `13608`. I used the int function around the value variables but in vain. Should I reformat my variable values or what am I missing.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not math error in awk.

You need to use `-v name=val` to pass arguments to `awk` and simplify your awk command:

```
awk -v tags=$tags -v pVal=$pVal -v fc=$fc '$6>tags && $7>pVal && int($8)>fc'
```

Comment: Gotcha, thank you!! I edited the title also.